# R: optimal sorting/allocation/distribution of items

Tags: r

I'm hoping someone may be able to help with a problem I have - trying to solve using R.

Individuals can submit requests for items. The minimum number of requests per person is one. There is a recommended maximum of five, but people can submit more in exceptional circumstances. Each item can only be allocated one individual.

Each item has a 'desirability'/quality score ranging from 10 (high quality) down to 0 (low quality). The idea is to allocate items, in line with requests, such that as many high quality items as possible are allocated. It is less important that individuals have an equitable spread of requests met.

Everyone has to have at least one request met. Next priority is to look at whether we can get anyone who is over the recommended limit within it by allocating requests to others. After that the priority is to look at where the item would rank in each individual's request list based on quality score, and allocate to the person where it would rank highest (eg, if it would be first in someone's list and third in another's, give it to the former).

Effectively I'd need a sorting algorithm of some kind that:

- Identifies where an item has been requested more than once
- Check all the requests of everyone making said request
- If that request is the only one a person has made, give it to them
  (if this scenario applies to more than one person, it should be
  flagged in some way)
- If all requestees have made more than one request, check to see if
  any have made more than five requests - if they have it can be taken 
  off them.
- If all are within the recommended limit, see where the request would
  rank (based on quality score) and give to the person in whose list it
  would rank highest.
- The process needs to check that the above step isn't happening to people so many times that it leaves them without any requests...so it
  effectively has to check one item at a time.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to approach this? I can think of all kinds of why I could arrange the data to make it easy to identify and see where this needs to happen, but not to automate the process itself. Thanks in advance for any help.

The data (at least the bits needed for this process) looks like the below:

```
Item ID Person ID   Item Score
1       AAG         9
1       AAK         8
2       AAAX        8
2       AN          8
2       AAAK        8
3       Z           8
3       K           8
4       AAC         7
4       AR          5
5       W          10
5       V           9
6       AAAM        7
6       AAAL        7
7       AAAAN       5
7       AAAAO       5
8       AB          9
8       D           9
9       AAAAK       6
9       AAAAC       6
10      A           3
10      AY          3
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: I don't have firm expectations as I'm not 100% sure what outputs are possible - an additional column inidicating to which person the item has been allocated to would be very useful. I assume that is the most straightfoward way of doing this but I may be completely wrong.